# android test methods in test class not run respectively

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

i have a test class and three test methods in it. problem is that when i run test, methods having @test annotation doest run in sequence they placed in class, first getWorkPlanWhenNotReady() runs then isWorkPlanReady() and last loginIsSuccessfull() runs. i want test methods run in sequence they placed in class , any help will be appereciated this is my test class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario;
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso;
import androidx.test.espresso.IdlingRegistry;
import androidx.test.espresso.IdlingResource;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.filters.MediumTest;
import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner;
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

import com.tips.schoolbusdriverapp.R;
import com.tips.schoolbusdriverapp.data.models.LoginPojo;
import com.tips.schoolbusdriverapp.data.models.MainModel;
import com.tips.schoolbusdriverapp.ui.login.LoginActivity;
import com.tips.schoolbusdriverapp.ui.login.LoginTestActivity;
import com.tips.schoolbusdriverapp.ui.login_easy.EasyLoginTestActivity;
import com.tips.schoolbusdriverapp.ui.main.MainActivity;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.clearText;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.doesNotExist;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.doesNotHaveFocus;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

/**
 * Instrumented AppDataBase, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MainScreenTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<LoginTestActivity> activityScenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(
            LoginTestActivity.class);

    private IdlingResource loginIdlingResource;
    private IdlingResource workPlanIdlingResource;
    private LoginTestActivity loginTestActivity;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;


    @Test
    public void loginIsSuccessfull() {
        activityScenarioRule.getScenario().onActivity(activity -> {
            loginTestActivity = activity;
            loginIdlingResource = activity.getEasyLoginIdlingResource();
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(activity.mIdlingResource);
        });
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext();
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.ed_email)).perform(clearText(), typeText("dri@gmail.com"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.ed_password)).perform(clearText(), typeText("1"), closeSoftKeyboard());
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.login))
                .perform(click());
        LoginPojo loginPojo = loginTestActivity.getLoginResponse();
        if (loginPojo.isSuccess()) {
            activityScenarioRule.getScenario().moveToState(Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED);
            runMainActivity(appContext);
        }
        else assertTrue(loginPojo.isSuccess());
    }

    @Test
    public void isWorkPlanReady() {
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.retryWP2)).check(doesNotExist());
    }

    @Test
    public void getWorkPlanWhenNotReady() {
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.retryWP2))
                .perform(click());
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.retryWP2)).check(doesNotExist());

    }

    public void runMainActivity(Context context) {
        ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule
                = new ActivityTestRule<>(
                MainActivity.class,
                true,
                false);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        activityRule.launchActivity(intent);
        mainActivity=activityRule.getActivity();
        workPlanIdlingResource=activityRule.getActivity().mIdlingResource;
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(workPlanIdlingResource);

    }
    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
        if (loginIdlingResource != null) {
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(loginTestActivity.mIdlingResource);
        }
        if(workPlanIdlingResource!=null){
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(mainActivity.mIdlingResource);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved problem by finding a description in this link :
[Running your tests in a specific order](https://www.ontestautomation.com/running-your-tests-in-a-specific-order/)

and cause i use junit ruuner to run test this annotation :
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
and naming methods with desired alphabetical names solved the problem